# KafkaStreams processing guarantee exactly_once and exactly_once_beta difference

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

The question is simple, what is the difference between those two guarantees in Kafka Streams?

`processing.guarantee`: `exactly_once` / `exactly_once_beta`

Docs says

> Using "exactly_once" requires broker version 0.11.0 or newer, while using "exactly_once_beta" requires broker version 2.5 or newer. Note that if exactly-once processing is enabled, the default for parameter commit.interval.ms changes to 100ms.

But there's nothing about difference.

Comment: You may find [KIP-447](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-447%3A+Producer+scalability+for+exactly+once+semantics) and [EOS Scalability Design](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1LhzHGeX7_Lay4xvrEXxfciuDWATjpUXQhrEIkph9qRE/mobilebasic) helpful.

Comment: It seems it's meant for BC purposes with older clients 

Answer (score 2):

When you configure `exactly_once_beta`, transaction processing will be done using a new implementation, enabling [better performance](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-447%3A+Producer+scalability+for+exactly+once+semantics) as the number of producers increases.

Note however that a [two-step migration](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/upgrade-guide.html#upgrading-your-kstreams-applications-to-cp-release) will be necessary if you have been using exactly_once with an earlier Kafka version.